# EF4 equivalent of NHibernate IUserType

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework-4, iusertype

I want to map a model property of type TimeZoneInfo to a column in the database.  In NHib, I just made an IUserType "TimeZoneInfoString" that converted back and forth and then used a typedef.  How can I do this type of work using Entity Framework 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't have equivalent to NHibernate's user types. You must create separate property in your entity for it and map only the string property. Somethink like:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone
    {
        get
        {
            return Parse(TimeZoneInfoString);
        }
        set
        {
            TimeZoneInfoString = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Where this class is your partial part to autogenerated entity. `TimeZoneInfoString` is property mapped in your entity and `Parse` and `ToString` contains your conversion logic.

Comment: How does this affect querying? For example, context.MyEntities.Where(e => e.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local);

Comment: Badly. You can't query properties from partial class. You must query that string property.

Comment: Well, the EF team seems pretty with it. I guess we can hope for a solution in the future. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to affect EF's query expression parsing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what do you exactly mean by query expression parsing?

Comment: EF takes an expression tree from LINQ and passes it to the Object Services API to be converted to a command tree.  Is there a way to hook into this process and register a custom expression to command conversion when some kind of condition exists.  If so, then I could handle the above query problem in this manner.

Comment: So something like query interceptor? As I know, it doesn't exist. But you can probably create custom extension method to `IQueryable` which will take `TimeZoneInfo` and makes where condition to `TimeZoneInfoString` instead.